# issue running an application that uses openCV 1.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, opencv

I am trying to run an application that can train and fit active appearance models for my research. The application is the AAM-library (and can be found here http://code.google.com/p/aam-library/)

I am using Visual Studio 2005 in Windows XP 64-bit. I am using openCV 1.0 because the developer of the application writes that he's not sure that the app will work with openCV 2.0.

I have compiled openCV and the AAM-library. When I try to run the AAM-library I get the error message:

> Unsupported format or combination of formats (The image/matrix format is not supported by the function) in function cvBoundingRect, C:\User\VP\opencv\cv\src\cvshapedescr.cpp(1171)

The developer writes in the readme that:

> In order to make it work, you must modify a bug in OpenCV and rebuild it:
>   cvBoundingRect() doesn't work fine. 
>   opencv/cv/src/cvshapedescr.cpp around line 1161 
>   replace CV_32SC1 to CV_32SC2 and CV_32FC1 to CV_32FC2.

I have done this. I have also rebuilt both openCV and the AAM-library. But I keep on getting the same error. I'm new to Visual Studio and openCV (and C++!) so may be missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a matrix that has exactly two columns and has a data type of CV_32F or CV_32S?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble running OpenCV 1.0 on 64bit systems when working with our image processing software for a robot project.  We used the legacy version because of some code files we had. We eventually had to move up to 2.2.  If you have already tried 2.0, is there anyway to remove that portion of the library?